# es7 function decotators with params to return loop

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-2016

I am working with tests and I would like to create somehow parametrized tests like in python.
For jest there is jest-each library but it's not what I would like to use and you need to write all variants in each. For example, if I have:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = [4, 5, 6]
```

And I want to test all possible combinations I need to set up:

```
each[[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]]...
```

I tried to set up just:

```
a.forEach(a => {
  b.forEach(b=>{})
})
```

I works fine but very unpretty with lots of params.

Can I create a decorator like

```
@parametrized(a, [1, 2, 3])
@parametrized(b, [3, 4, 5])
test()
```

to be the same as for Each in previous example.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no decorators in ES7. Given the history of the experimental proposal, which version exactly do you want to use?

Comment: `@parametrized(a, [1, 2, 3])` won't work since you'll get reference error from the not defined `a`. You could however write something like `@parametrized([1, 2, 3]) @parametrized([3, 4, 5]) a => b => { … }`.

Comment: I use node 14.15 with switched on --experimental-vm-modules flag

Comment: Node.js does not natively support decorators at all, regardless of flags.

Comment: I see that class decos are supported. And class methods. But not functional. But thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're not using a transpiler?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation for these natively supported decorators, please?

Comment: You are right, decorators are still in draft and cannot be used without babel transpilation.

Comment: So which babel plugin (version) with what settings are you using/planning to use?

Comment: I decided to to setup babel as this leads to difficulties with debugging named imports